# How to pre-register attendees to an event?

Tags: meetup

How would one pre-register a member to an event one creates on Meetup.com?

I.e. I speak to member X, who would love to do something specific on Saturday but at my place. I would like to create this event but I only have a few spots for something that may fill up without giving member X a chance to sign up. I really think X should be there (it was his idea in the first place) and would like to reserve a spot for him.

How can I do this? If it isn't currently a feature - how should I handle it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle it so far:

After creating the event,

1. Click on the meetup to go to its page.
2. Click "tools" (immediately above the event host's profile picture and next to the "email attendees" button).
3. Click "edit RSVPs".
4. Use the find member function to display the member you'd like to reserve a spot for.
5. Select "attending" next to his profile picture.